# Render variable from layout to another layout

Tags: php, yii

In layout I am getting some value:

```
$quote = Quotes::model()->findAll(array('order'=>'id DESC', 'limit'=>1));
```

And it works Ok, no matter it is a bad practice to call model from view.
In another layout in the same folder I cant do the same. If it matters, this layouts shows on the same page. I am responding straight to the Model and the Controller doesnt render any variables to view.
Is there a way to send this var to custom layout or view?

Comment: Whatever layout is set in your controller of Yii that layout only can access this but if your are going to use same thing in another layout which is not defined in your action or controller then it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method inside your controller that will return the value you need, and then you can call this method from view. Or if you are using $this->render() inside your view, then you just have to pass this variable forward to your custom view: $this->render('quotes',$quotes);

Answer (score 0):

I put this line before `$quote` and it worked!

```
Yii::import('application.modules.quotes.models.*');
```

Not sure, how it works, maybe this is my particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that put the model inside the views/layout directly is the best practice. For some reason, I put a public variable, called $settings inside my Controller.php and put it inside the protected/components/

```
class Controller extends CController {
    protected $settings = array();

    public function init() {
        $this->settings = Settings::model()->getAllSettings();
    }

    public function getSetting($key = '')
    {
        if (isset($this->settings[$key]))
        {
            return CHtml::decode($this->settings[$key]);
        }
        return NULL;
    }


}
```

So inside my layout (main.php), I would do it this way.

```
<h1>Welcome to <?php echo $this->getSetting('brand_name');?>
```

The real code may look more complicated than the above, but I hope it helps you a little bit.